# Change save location of clips by GameBar in win 10

Tags: windows-10

I found this [website](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8630-record-take-screenshots-game-bar-windows-10-a.html) which shows, where the videos will be stored. Sadly this folder is on my SSD and I want to change the location to a (custom) folder on my HDD. In the settings of the GameBar I couldn't find anything to change the save location.

Which ways are there and which way would you recommend to change the save location for the clips?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Which ways are there and which way would you recommend to change the
>   save location for the clips?

You should just move the Captures folder.

> To find your game clips and screenshots from **Game DVR**, select the
>   **Start** button, choose the **Xbox** app in the Start menu, and then go to **Settings**  > **Game DVR** > **Saving captures** and select
>   **Open folder**.
>
> To change where your game clips are saved, use File Explorer to move
>   the **Captures** folder anywhere you want on your PC. Game DVR will
>   continue saving your game clips and screenshots in that folder
>   wherever you put it.

[Where are my Game DVR clips and screenshots saved in Windows 10?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/f7a118fa-568f-b1c7-d915-f0de184e2907/where-are-my-game-dvr-clips-and-screenshots-saved-in-windows-10)

You can also move the Videos profile directory itself.

> 1. Open up **This PC**.
> 2. In the navigation pane (left-pane), right-click on the **Videos** folder and then click **Properties**. This action will open **Videos
>      Properties**.
>
> [image]
>
> 3. Switch to the **Location** tab.
> 4. Click the **Move** button, browse to the location where you would like to save Game DVR clips and the Videos folder. Click **Select
>      Folder** button.
>
> [image]
>   [image]
>
> 5. Finally, once the folder locatin has been changed click the **Apply** button. When you see the following confirmation dialog, click the **Yes** button.
>
> [image]

[How To Change Game DVR Folder (Captures) Location In Windows 10](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-change-game-dvr-folder-captures-location-in-windows-10/)

Comment: Clicking on Captures->Open folder takes me to my %TEMP% folder. Moving my Videos folder doesn't change this to another folder.

Comment: The answer is identical to Microsoft's official explanation of how to change the recording location. My comment isn't asking a new question, it's explaining that this answer does not apply to everybody. Changing the recording location only works if the currently registered location is still valid, otherwise Windows will indicate that the recording location is your %TEMP% folder and it won't allow you to change that.